# Синхронный Promise в Nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

Как сделать промис синхронным?

```
async function some() {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("Two"), 3000);
    }).then(data => {
      return data;
    }).catch(err => {
      return err;
    });

    return await promise;
}

console.log("One");
console.log(some());
console.log("Three");
```

Должно быть:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function some() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Two"), 3000);
  }).then(data => {
    return data;
  }).catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
}

(async function() {
  console.log("One");
  console.log(await some());
  console.log("Three");
})()
```

Comment: Это немного не то, что я хотел. Этой функции нельзя задать имя, а мне нужно ее экспортировать через module.exports. Она должна замораживать процесс node до тех пор пока не произойдет tcp подключение через библиотеку net.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно. Экспортируйте и вызывайте ее так же через await.

Comment: А вот просто "заморозить процесс" нельзя, потому что тогда подключение никогда не произойдет. Event loop, и все такое.